# Docker swarm change advertise-addr if leader node fails

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Scenario: A swarm cluster of 5 nodes, with three managers M1 (leader), M2, M3 and two workers W1, W2. The advertise-addr for the swarm was the IP address of M1.

If M1 for some reason fails and is no longer part of the cluster, I find that I cannot promote a worker node to a manager or even rejoin M1 in as a manager.

The quorum of managers is still fine as two managers exists, so the swarm service are not disturbed.

How do you handle this scenario, is there a way we can update advertise-addr of the swarm to point to the new leader when M1 left?